# How to write QPA plugin that acts as a window manager

Tags: windows, qt, window-managers

I'm working on some kind of window manager application in Qt under Windows. My approach would be to have a main application that controls the visibility and geometries of (frameless) main windows of some child processes via ipc. This has the advantage that child processes can crash without affecting the main application. The downside will be that the screen is split into many independent windows floating around.

Now I'm searching for a solutions to get all child processes to draw into one window and have the events (mouse and key events for example) handled by the right child process.

Would be a custom QPA plugin a good solution? I think it could hanlde this main window via `QSharedMemory` for example and all child processes will draw its content into its `QWindowsBackingStore` regarding to the given geometry and visibility. How to start with such a plugin?

Is there another solution under Windows that could be more suitable for this?
Could be the [CreateDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in the Window API a candidate?

Comment: `a solution to get all child processes to draw into one window` care to explain? You also want them to behave as widgets of a single process if I understood correctly? Like what [QX11EmbedWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qx11embedwidget.html#details) does for linux?

Comment: Yes, they should behave exactly like that QX11EmbedWidget but under Windows.